# How can I restrict branch acces to specific users of Git on centos 7 server?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-server

I successfully configured centos 7 machine as git server. Now, I have a requirement where I want to keep some documents on a branch(say some admin branch) which should be accessible to few of my teammates and not for other teammates.

How can I achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lightweight solution would be to manage ACL (Access Control Levels) through [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview.html).

It is just an authorization layer, which can be enough for a few members.

A more complete (but complex) option would be to [install GitLab CE](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/).